# ls -g: 'man ls' says -g option has no effect, but it works

Tags: command-line, zsh

macOS 14.3, zsh 5.9 (x86_64-apple-darwin23.0). `man ls`:

> `-g`: This option has no effect.  It is only available for compatibility with 4.3BSD, where it was used to display the group name in the long (`-l`) format output.

But it definitily works.

`ls -l`:

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 john  staff   0 Mar 13 09:06 file1.txt
-rw-r--r--@ 1 john  staff   0 Mar 13 09:06 file2.txt
drwxr-xr-x  2 john  staff  64 Mar 13 09:06 folder1
drwxr-xr-x  2 john  staff  64 Mar 13 09:06 folder2
```

`ls -g`:

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 staff   0 Mar 13 09:06 file1.txt
-rw-r--r--@ 1 staff   0 Mar 13 09:06 file2.txt
drwxr-xr-x  2 staff  64 Mar 13 09:06 folder1
drwxr-xr-x  2 staff  64 Mar 13 09:06 folder2
```

and `ls -go`:

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1    0 Mar 13 09:06 file1.txt
-rw-r--r--@ 1    0 Mar 13 09:06 file2.txt
drwxr-xr-x  2   64 Mar 13 09:06 folder1
drwxr-xr-x  2   64 Mar 13 09:06 folder2
```

How this is possible? And is it future-proof to use `ls -g` in scripts?

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs (and the discussion at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead) why using the output of `ls` in scripts is a bad idea, and what the alternative approaches are.

Comment: Just FYI, nothing is "future proof". Just ask anyone who bought an Xserve. If you script it and `-g`, the worst that will happen is it errors out at which time you'll have to fix your script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the `man ls` output for the `-g` option changed with the release of Monterey, the behavior with respect to both the `-g` and `-o` options has not since at least Snow Leopard. Basically, the previous description is probably better than the current description. As [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan) already stated in a [comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/700879): *nothing is "future proof"*. Some details are given below.

The OP offered a partial description. The complete description is given below.

```
     -g      This option has no effect.  It is only available for
             compatibility with 4.3BSD, where it was used to display the group
             name in the long (-l) format output.  This option is incompatible
             with IEEE Std 1003.1-2008 (“POSIX.1”).
```

The complete description starting from Leopard 10.5 though Big Sur 13.5 is given below.

```
     -g      This option is only available for compatibility with POSIX; it is
             used to display the group name in the long (-l) format output
             (the owner name is suppressed).
```

While not part of IEEE Std 1003.1-2008, the following is given in the `ls` [specifications](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2008edition/utilities/ls.html).

[image: ls]

The current IEEE Std 1003.1-2017 (Revision of IEEE Std 1003.1-2008) has the following for `ls` [specifications](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html).

[image: current ls]

The behavior shown in the OP's question has been tested (by me) to be the same on the following versions of OS X/macOS:

- Ventura 13.3.1 (a)
- Monterey 12.5
- Catalina 10.15.7
- High Sierra 10.13.6
- Snow Leopard 10.6

BTW, the following `man ls` output for the `-o` option has also not changed since Leopard 10.5.

```
     -o      List in long format, but omit the group id.
```